# Data import to API using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where i have the data in the csv file (source) and import the file into an API. To provide an example, I have customer data in a CSV file that needs to be imported into an API. This process involves transforming the source data into a JSON format, making an API call, and creating a customer. Does anyone have a reference or information on how to accomplish this? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Thanks

looking for sample reference

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If your csv file rows are less than 5000 rows**, you can use the lookup activity to achieve your requirement.

Create a delimited text dataset for the CSV and use that in lookup activity. Make sure you uncheck the **First row only** in lookup.

Sample csv data:

```
Id  Name    Age marks
1   Rakesh  22  90
2   Bhavan  23  26
3   sai 21  70
4   kiran   24  62
5   kowsik  20  80
1   Rakesh  22  24
5   kowsik  20  29
8   arun    25  30
3   sai 21  13
10  virat   20  79
```

Lookup will give the JSON array like below in its output.

[image]

Use this JSON array in web activity with below expression.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. According to our specifications, the CSV file's row count may exceed 5000. Additionally, we have a new requirement: we need to make an API call to import data and utilize a callback URL to determine the import's status (Success/Failure). Based on this status, we'll need to decide whether the pipeline is a success or a failure. While I was researching, I came across a Microsoft article that mentioned achieving this using either a Web activity or a Web hook, but I couldn't find a suitable reference. Appreciate your help here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Are you able to help here?

Thanks

Comment: The web activity also have size limitation. If the data is more than 5000, First use dataflow to divide the source file into some equally sized files. First create a string variable named `json_str`in pipeline with empty string value. Then use get meta data activity to list out these files. Use ForEach. Inside Foreach, use lookup activity on each file.  Now, convert this lookupo array into string and skip the first `[` and last `]` and store in a `curr_json` string variable using set variable activity. Now, take another string variable `temp` and store the `json_str` value.

Comment: After that, using set variable to activity to `json_str` variable, concat the `temp` and `curr_json` string. In each iteration of loop this will repeat. After Foreach activity, take an array variable `res_json_array`. Convert the `json_str` variable to array and store it in the `res_json_array` variable using `@json(variables('json_str'))` expression in  a set varibale activity. This `res_json_array` will be array of objects which you can use as per your requirement.